# CSS skewY transition bug in Safari (desktop and mobile)

Tags: css, animation, safari, transform, skew

The issue is visible when animating the **skewY()** property. Looks like the element's width shrinks down a little and no longer touches the sides of an equally wide container.

The same does not happen when animating with **skewX()** - the height is animated as expected.

I'm experiencing the bug in Safari only, both desktop and mobile browsers. Firefox and Chrome work as expected. This issue is visible during transition or animations only.

GIF previews:

[Animation in Firefox/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7e5i.gif)

[Animation in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efod7.gif)

```css
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.rect-x {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50vw - 50px);
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: skew-x 1s linear alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.rect-y {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: skew-y 1s linear alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes skew-x {
  0% { transform: skewX(15deg) skewY(0); }
  to { transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-0);}
}

@keyframes skew-y {
  0% { transform: skewX(0) skewY(15deg); }
  to { transform: skewX(0) skewY(-15deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="rect-y"></div>
  <div class="rect-x"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use browser prefix.

```css
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.rect-x {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50vw - 50px);
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: skew-x 1s linear alternate infinite;
  -webkit-animation: skew-x 1s linear alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}

.rect-y {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: skew-y 1s linear alternate infinite;
  -webkit-animation: skew-y 1s linear alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center; 
}

@keyframes skew-x {
  0% { transform: skewX(15deg) skewY(0); }
  to { transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes skew-x {
  0% { -webkit-transform: skewX(15deg) skewY(0); }
  to { -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg) skewY(-0);}
}

@keyframes skew-y {
  0% { transform: skewX(0) skewY(15deg); }
  to { transform: skewX(0) skewY(-15deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes skew-y {
  0% { -webkit-transform: skewX(0) skewY(15deg); }
  to { -webkit-transform: skewX(0) skewY(-15deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="rect-y"></div>
  <div class="rect-x"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not change the Safari behavior. Did it work on Safari for you or that was only a suggestion?

Comment: I tried it of course. On 4 devices. Here's a video  and it shows the same problem. On which Safari are you testing it and it works? I've tried iPhone and iPad on 13, MacOS Mojave and MacOS High Sierra with the same results. [Sreen preview](https://imgur.com/dW1sYmt)